# Filter information from another sheet with two different criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a [spreadsheet](http://goo.gl/DDcmzP) where data comes in from a Google Form. I am trying to group the responses I get by different parts of the country. For example, if someone from Boston and another from New York City submit forms, I want to display their submissions under a group **East Coast.**

The group is in a separate sheet and at the moment I am using the current formula to get the information from Sheet1:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:E,"Select * Where C = """&B1&""" ")
```

I can only show B1, which is Boston, but I would also like to include C1, New York City.

How can I modify this to reflect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:E,"Select * Where C = """&B1&""" or C = 'New York City' ")
```